# Html coding showing ... instead of 3d gallery

Tags: html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor      (www.coffeecup.com)">
   <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Sat, 23 May 2015 03:43:17 GMT">
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="keywords" content="">
   <title></title>



     <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">      </script>

 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="cp_widget_98408491-377f-4723-bc95-325b1e38a559">...</div>      <script  type="text/javascript"> var cpo = []; cpo["_object"] 
  ="cp_widget_98408491-377f-4723-bc95-325b1e38a559"; cpo["_fid"] = 
 "AsBA_i8ngTz5"; var _cpmp = _cpmp || []; _cpmp.push(cpo); (function() { 
var cp = document.createElement("script"); cp.type = "text/javascript"; cp.async = true; cp.src = "//www.cincopa.com/media-platform/runtime  /libasync.js"; var c = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];  c.parentNode.insertBefore(cp, c); })(); </script><noscript>Powered by
Cincopa <a href='http://www.cincopa.com  /video-hosting'>Video Hosting for
Business</a> solution.</noscript>
```

I have a link ^^^ and I know this works off of cincopa

My problem I am having is that the code prints out ... instead of the 3d gallery

Comment: I have the rest of the code its properly ended with

Comment: Also to add this code works perfectly on w3schools.com's editor. I use coffecup editor

Answer (score 1):

so I pasted your code in my editor and fixed some spacing and added in some http:// where they were missing and now it works (for me at least).

//www.cincopa.com/media-platform/runtime  /libasync.js <-- you were missing http: and you have a huge space after "runtime".

http://www.cincopa.com  /video-hosting <-- you have huge space after the .com

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
       <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Sat, 23 May 2015 03:43:17 GMT">
       <meta name="description" content="">
       <meta name="keywords" content="">
       <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cp_widget_98408491-377f-4723-bc95-325b1e38a559">...</div><script  type="text/javascript"> var cpo = []; cpo["_object"] 
      ="cp_widget_98408491-377f-4723-bc95-325b1e38a559"; cpo["_fid"] = 
     "AsBA_i8ngTz5"; var _cpmp = _cpmp || []; _cpmp.push(cpo); (function() { 
    var cp = document.createElement("script"); cp.type = "text/javascript"; cp.async = true; cp.src = "http://www.cincopa.com/media-platform/runtime/libasync.js"; var c = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];  c.parentNode.insertBefore(cp, c); })(); </script><noscript>Powered by
    Cincopa <a href='http://www.cincopa.com/video-hosting'>Video Hosting for
    Business</a> solution.</noscript>

         <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried that code and still receive the same output of just three dots. Its supposed to show a 3d image gallery. I have provided the test page sent via email from cincopa the link is: http://www.cincopa.com/media-platform/test?fid=AsBA_i8ngTz5. Instead of the 3d gallery i get 3 dots and I do not know why.

Comment: That's weird I see the 3D Gallery. 

Here is what I see
[link]http://gyazo.com/c82cf30ab50a5925d55fda49f4a136e0
[link]http://gyazo.com/ae3f5b7de8dd94831a544b5d677c38fd

Comment: What program are you using to code? And what browser? Do you have windows? and do you have php or js installed?

Comment: I'm using Adobe Edge Code CC to code and the browser I used was Chrome and I'm on a Windows 7 machine. I also just tried it on Firefox and it worked.

Comment: Do you know what I am doing wrong? I am using Firefox, windows 8, and tried multiple coding programs (coffecup and notepad++)

Comment: That code I pasted should work. just remove what code you had and paste what I posted and that should work. Make sure your browsers are up to date but it should be working.

Comment: OK lets try clearing your browsers cach. So for chrome go to the history to do this you can click ctrl+H and then go to "Clear Browsing Data" and then uncheck everything except the "Catched images and Files" so you should have something like this [link]http://gyazo.com/e17fda8acb72719fd9b4c5064859681b then click clear browsing data and close the browser and try again.

Comment: i did that but still nothing it only shows three .'s like ... in the whole webpage

Comment: As you can see it works perfect on this editor: link : http://gyazo.com/e47b0eee35c82e839d427db3a197a7a4

Comment: Yes that's what I see on my browser.

Comment: Do you have Team Viewer, join.me or anything like that? Maybe I can remote in and help you.

Comment: Ready for my id and pass?

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing this is for Team Viewer

Comment: Correct, id : 521 651 438 pass: 2174

Comment: Wait it accidentally closed and changed user; 521 651 438 pass: 4330